# I'm looking to begin making product spaces of polynomials..

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, resultant

I'm studying a [definition of a resultant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1sAa.png) so I have to compute the product of two vector spaces $\mathcal{P}^{i}$ with elements that are polynomials of degree less than $i$. If $1+x \in \mathcal{P}^{2}$ and $2+x+x^{2} \in \mathcal{P}^{3}$ then is their element in the product space $\mathcal{P}^{2}\times \mathcal{P}^{3}$ the element $(1,x,2,x,x^{2})$? That is what I guess to do from [this slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJvVC.png) of a powerpoint

I have to find out how $\mathcal{P}^{2}\times \mathcal{P}^{3} \simeq \mathcal{P}^{5}$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the element in $\mathcal{P}^2\times\mathcal{P}^3$, one would typically write
$$
(1+x,2+x+x^2)
$$
to indicate how the elements are grouped.

The isomorphism to $\mathcal{P}^5$ isn't natural - it involves a choice.  If a chosen basis for $\mathcal{P}^2$ is $\{1,x\}$ and a chosen basis for $\mathcal{P}^3$ is $\{1,x,x^2\}$, then a basis for $\mathcal{P}^2\times\mathcal{P}^3$ is
$$
\{(1,0)\;,\;
(x,0)\;,\;
(0,1)\;,\;
(0,x)\;,\;
(0,x^2)\}.
$$

On the other hand, a basis for $\mathcal{P}^5$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$.  Then, one can pair up the basis elements of $\mathcal{P}^2\times\mathcal{P}^3$ with those of $\mathcal{P}^5$.

Therefore, $(1+x,2+x+x^2)$ in $\mathcal{P}^2\times\mathcal{P}^3$ would correspond to $1+x+2x^2+x^3+x^4$, but this isomorphism is only as vector spaces and has limited ring-theoretic properties.